# difference of sie vs ihr in a sentence for english word her

Tags: english-to-german

The English sentence:
He warned her yesterday; He told me to come here this morning, that he would introduce me to her.

is translated to German by google translator as

Er hat **sie** gestern gewarnt; Er sagte mir, ich solle heute Morgen hierher kommen, um mich **ihr** vorzustellen.

The question is why the first her is sie and the 2nd one ihr? is the first case akkusive and the 2nd case dative?

Comment: Yes, the first is accusative and the second dative. Was that your actual problem or did something confuse you?

Answer (score 2):

English conflates accusative case and dative case into a single case: *objective case*. In German we tell those two apart.

What may confuse you is that the feminine personal pronoun has both *sie* for nominative and accusative singular in German. While English tells those apart with *she* vs *her*.

This is common in German: nominative and accusative forms usually only differ in masculine singular.